# AppSetting >>" ApplyHostAsOrigin": true,

Tags: iis, load-balancing, appsettings

What is the use of **"ApplyHostAsOrigin"**?

I have an IIS web server and host a website on that server. If I add a load balancer and pass all the requests through load balancer it gives me an error. Someone recommends adding  ApplyHostAsOrigin as true in the appsetting.json file and it solved the issue.

Comment: I can't find any document mentioned the configuration “ApplyHostAsOrigin”. It seems to be a custom configuration parameter applied for your application. We can only know the use of this configuration by reviewing your source code.  According to the verbatim description, it sounds like your application will add host name to CORS header when it is set to true. So your load balance could load source file correctly.

Comment: @JokiesDing Thank you, I will ask my dev team about it.